# Java scanner used in an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I am new at Java and am currently trying to create a super super simple code just to test how to have a scanner input compared in an if statement to another number and then print out a response depending on the if. This is what I have and I'm getting an error on the if line and I'm getting this error:

```
The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int.
```

Any help would be great because once I figure this out I'm going to try to do some other things with it. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class damagecalc {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How much damage did you do?");
    String damage = input.nextLine();

    if(damage > 50){
        System.out.println("You have died!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Your damage amount is:" + input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you even READ the error? It is telling you *exactly* what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Yes, however as mentioned above I'm brand spanking new to Java. I don't know what I need to do to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare `String`s using `>` operator. In Java you cannot define your own operator behaviour.

Instead of

```
String damage = input.nextLine();
```

use

```
Integer damage = input.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
String damage = input.nextLine();
```

You want

```
int damage = input.nextInt();
```

And this

```
System.out.println("Your damage amount is:" + input);
```

Should be

```
System.out.println("Your damage amount is:" + damage);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare string with integer. Just parse it.

```
  try {
        if (Integer.parseInt(damage) > 50) {i
             System.out.println("You have died!");
        } else {
             System.out.println("Your damage amount is:" + input);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("You have entered a non integer number!");
    }
```

Comment: Why would `damage` be `null`?

Comment: Based on your edit, if the user enters an empty string, the else block will execute (I don't think the OP wants this).

Comment: So what you are thinking ? Empty `string` can be `> 50` ??

Comment: If you use `Integer.parseInt` on an empty `String`, an `Exception` will be thrown anyway. You need to remove the `!damage.isEmpty()` condition from your if statement. If the user enters an empty `String`, the output will be "Your damage amount is:" which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a more robust solution, perhaps you could try something like:

```
public static int readInt(final String prompt){
    final Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        System.out.println(prompt);
        try{
            return Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("Enter a valid integer: " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd probably suggest declaring your `Scanner` as a static class field if you plan on reading multiple user input (which presumably you do). You could invoke it like:

```
final int damage = readInt("How much damage did you do?");
System.out.println(damage > 50 ? "You have died!" : ("Your damage amount is: " + damage));
```